# How to use rga (ripgrep-all) with fzf for searching the pdf file and then using sioyek to open that file with its page number?

Tags: pdf, fzf, ripgrep

How to using rga (ripgrep-all) with fzf for searching the pdf file and then using sioyek to open that file with its page number?

Like this nvim script with rg :
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## 1. Search for text in files using Ripgrep

## 2. Interactively narrow down the list using fzf

## 3. Open the file in Vim

```bash
rg --color=always --line-number --no-heading --smart-case "${*:-}" |
  fzf --ansi \
      --color "hl:-1:underline,hl+:-1:underline:reverse" \
      --delimiter : \
      --preview 'bat --color=always {1} --highlight-line {2}' \
      --preview-window 'up,60%,border-bottom,+{2}+3/3,~3' \
      --bind 'enter:become(nvim {1} +{2})'
```

I have found a similar fzf for rga from their official websites:

```
rga-fzf() {
    RG_PREFIX="rga --files-with-matches"
    local file
    file="$(
        FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="$RG_PREFIX '$1'" \
            fzf -m --sort --preview="[[ ! -z {} ]] && rga --pretty --context 3 {q} {}" \
                --phony -q "$1" \
                --bind "change:reload:$RG_PREFIX {q}" \
                --preview-window="80%:wrap"
    )" &&
    echo "opening $file" &&
    open "$file"
}
```

I want make it become sioyek "$file" --pages "page_number " etc

Thanks !!

I tried to using awk to grep the first part of the fzf result:
`rga -t f ( rga type : pdf)`

result :
some file name.pdf:Page 42:sentense that contains my searching words

But I don't know how to awk the page, or using built in function from rg to achieve this

One more similar example :

```
skrga() {
    local file
    file="$(sk-tmux --bind "ctrl-p:toggle-preview" --ansi -i --cmd-query "$*" -c 'rga --ignore-case --color=always --line-number --column {}' --preview 'bat --color=always --style=header,numbers --highlight-line "$(echo {1}|cut -d: -f2)" --line-range "$(($(echo {1}|cut -d: -f2))):$(($(echo {1}|cut -d: -f2)+50))" "$(echo {1}|cut -d: -f1)"')"; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "opening $file" && subl "$(echo "$file"|cut -d: -f1):$(echo "$file"|cut -d: -f2):$(echo "$file"|cut -d: -f3)" || return 1;
}
```

Thanks!